# How to deserialize only parts of a file using Boost in C++?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

I have a number of instances of the same class that I serialize using `boost::archive::binary_oarchive`. They are saved in a given order. I am only interested in loading one of them and I know its position. How do I retrieve (deserialize) that one object without having to deserialize almost everything?

More generally, what is the best way to retrieve only some objects from a file?

Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
std::ofstream saveFile("savefile.save");

boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(saveFile);
oa << arrayOfObjects;
        
saveFile.close();

// Later...

std::ifstream loadFile("savefile.save");

boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(loadFile);
ia >> arrayOfObjects;

auto oneSpecificObject = arrayOfObjects[i]; // I have to do this; not efficient

loadFile.close();
```

Thanks in advance and cheers,

Comment: When you say you know the position of the object, you mean the byte position in the file?

Comment: I know the position of the object relative to the other object but not the position in bytes, although I'm sure I can deduce it from the size of the objects. I've tried using `seekg` but it didn't work and I couldn't find anything similar that works with Boost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what the exact type of `arrayOfObjects` is.

Because *that* is the deciding factor on how things get serialized.

If it is a true array, things might not even be too complicated. Though it becomes pretty tricky again as soon as object tracking is involved. E.g.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60ffc096eab84203)**

```
X x{"the answer is 42"};
// std::vector arrayOfObject { &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x }; // OR:
X* arrayOfObject[] = { &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x };

{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << arrayOfObject;
}
```

Prints

```
22 serialization::archive 19 8 0 1 0
0 16 the answer is 42 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Hence, naively reading back only the 6th element would lead to... unspecified results. So, my recommendation would be to /just read the entire array/ and discard all the data you didn't need.

### Hacking It

If we are going to be unsafe, assuming no complicating factors like mentioned and depending on the implementation details (e.g. how a vector is actually serialized), you can write deserialization to match and get the behaviour you wished:

**[Live On Coliru - Don't Try This At Home](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a8949ebd71e4fb9)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#ifndef TYPE
#define TYPE xml
#endif
using oarchive = boost::archive::BOOST_PP_CAT(TYPE, _oarchive);
using iarchive = boost::archive::BOOST_PP_CAT(TYPE, _iarchive);

struct X {
    std::string answer;
    void serialize(auto& ar, unsigned) { ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(answer); }
};

template <typename T, size_t TargetIndex>
struct FakeVectorReader {
    T element;

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned)
    {
        static_assert(typename Ar::is_loading{});
        using namespace boost::serialization;

        collection_size_type count;
        ar >> make_nvp("count", count);

        if (library_version_type(3) < ar.get_library_version()) {
            item_version_type item_version(0);
            ar >> make_nvp("item_version", item_version);
        }

        assert(count > TargetIndex);

        T v;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            ar >> make_nvp("item", v);
            if (i == TargetIndex) {
                element = std::move(v);
                ar.reset_object_address(&element, &v); // a bit half-hearted, this
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector const arrayOfObject{
        X{"zero"}, {"one"}, {"two"},   {"three"}, {"four"},
        {"five"},  {"six"}, {"seven"}, {"eight"}, {"nine"},
    };

    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        oarchive oa(ss);
        oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(arrayOfObject);
    }

    if (std::string("binary") != BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(TYPE)) {
        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }

    {
        iarchive ia(ss);
        FakeVectorReader<X, 6> hack;
        ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("arrayOfObject", hack);

        std::cout << "hack.element: " << hack.element.answer << "\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
22 serialization::archive 19 0 0 10 0 0 0 4 zero 3 one 3 two 5 three 4 four 4 five 3 six 5 seven 5 eight 4 nine
hack.element: six
```

### Don't Try This At Home

I'm trusting you will use this knowledge wisely.

- I delved deep into the implementation details,
- did a half-hearted lip-service to object tracking there, knowing that it will break when objects are actually aliased within an archive
- should caution that all of this will break if you so much as change the container type or
- even upgrade to a newer version of the Boost Library.
- keep in mind that all elements are actually deserialized (this is so that if more data follows the array then at least you can still read that).
- It will leak if `X` is not safe (follows Rule-Of-3/5/0)

I hope the answer helps to illustrate why you shouldn't, and perhaps if somehow you **cannot** avoid this (you need to deserialize a part of that multi-terabyte archive, but don't have access to the supercomputer anymore?)

Comment: Updated live demo with test for [XML](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/117d111d81e073d8), [Binary](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a8949ebd71e4fb9) and [Text](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aefbb57e33ad7ccb) archives.